# How to save the model trained in SmartCore?

Tags: machine-learning, rust

I use [SmartCore](https://smartcorelib.org/) to fit a simple KNN model to [Breast Cancer data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29). How can I save results of `KNNClassifier::fit` to reuse the model later?

Comment: Looks like they have a section on using `serde` with their models on their site. https://smartcorelib.org/user_guide/model_selection.html#model-persistence

Answer (score 1):

As LinearZoetrope mentioned you can serialize your model into a string or a byte stream using [`serde`](https://serde.rs/). There is a section in the user's manual that describes how to save your model to a file: https://smartcorelib.org/user_guide/model_selection.html#model-persistence